# Let User Choose AirPrint OutputType

Tags: ios, swift, output, airprint, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am using the following code to airprint stuff:

```
let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
printInfo.outputType = .General
printInfo.jobName = "PrintImage"
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
printController.printInfo = printInfo
printController.printingItem = myImageView.image
printController.presentFromRect(button.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

Is there a way to let the user choose between the output types (`.GrayScale` or `.General` i.e.)?

I tried `printInfo.outputType = [.General, .GrayScale]` but that did not work...

Thanks in advance :)